# How delete a pythom list from scene ID properties?

Tags: python, properties, scene

I created a list using this method:

```
# assign a list
>>> C.scene["mylist"] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> C.scene['mylist']
<bpy id property array [6]>
# save file, reopen
>>> C.scene['mylist'].to_list()
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

But how can I delete it completely[image]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`del C.scene['mylist']` is [a standard way](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) of removing keys from dict-like objects in Python. It seems to work here, but I don't know if there are any pitfalls for doing this in Blender.
[image]

Comment: AFAIK that is the recommend way.